# Footable in Asp.Net MVC Https azure

Tags: footable

We use footable in a Asp.net Mvc app. It works fine when running on http.
But when we run thr same app on https from Azure it fails with the error:

```
(function ($, w, undefined) {
    if (w.footable === undefined || w.footable === null)
        throw new Error('Please check and make sure footable.js is included in the page and is loaded prior to this script.');
```

Some ideas?
And what is the best practice for footable in bundles, and where to place it in the _Layout-file?

Answer (score 0):

That error seems to be coming from one of the FooTable extensions (pagination, filtering, etc). The error is likely caused by one of these extensions loading before the FooTable core script itself.

What version of FooTable are you using? It seems likely that you are using V2?
If so, try including the footable.all.min.js as that includes the core footable and the base extensions in a single file

Comment: Thank you so much.
The footable.all.min.js did the job!